# symfony 1.4x and sfjQueryPlugin

Tags: jquery, symfony1, plugins

I want to install sfJQueryReloadedPlugin in my project. I have read on the official site that is the plugin will replace sfJQueryPlugin (which doesn't work with the most recent versions of symfony).

But I have an error : it tells me this plugin isn't support by symfony 1.4 and it's a plugin to symfony 1.0.

So I want to know if there are the same plugin for symfony 1.4 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you download the archive, unzip it into your plugins directory and enable it in your project configuration you will be able to use it fine.

http://plugins.symfony-project.org/get/sfJqueryReloadedPlugin/sfJqueryReloadedPlugin-1.4.1.tgz

Comment: Thanks,

Can I do it for sfFPDFPlugin because I have the same problem ?

Comment: You can do that for any plugin. Download link is on the plugin page.